# Issue when using malloc and realloc in 2D matrix

Tags: c

I want to output 2D Matrix using `malloc` and `realloc` only. I don't know what is wrong in my following code:

```
int s = (int)sqrt(9);
int i,j,k;
int **M;
M = malloc(sizeof(int));

k = 0;
while(k<s) {
    for(i=0;i<s;i++) {
        M = realloc(M, sizeof(int));
        M[k][i] = 5;
    }
    k++;
}

for(i=0;i<s;i++){
    for(j=0;j<s;j++){
        printf("%d \t",M[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It doesn't print out the matrix and I don't see where the problem is. Appreciate any hint.

Comment: Neither `malloc` nor `realloc` do any output, so I do not know how you expect to output anything with these two functions alone.

Comment: Yes I am a beginner in C .. I am sorry

Comment: There is no matrix / 2D **array**.

Comment: when calling `malloc()` and/or `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.    If `realloc()` fails, then, in the posted code, the original pointer to the allocated memory is overwritten with a NULL, resulting in a memory leak as the original pointer cannot be recovered.   SO, when calling `realloc()`, always assign the result to a temporary pointer, check (!=NULL) the temporary pointer and if not NULL, then assign the temporary pointer to the actual pointer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's unclear what you are asking. I assume that you want to create a square matrix of size `s` and then print it.

There are several mistakes in your code. First of all, get rid of that realloc: even though you can use it to allocate memory, it's built to reallocate the memory once it's already allocated.

Then, you allocate the wrong amount of memory. At the first allocation, you want to allocate `s` times the size of an `int*`. At the second allocation, you want to allocate `s` times the size of an `int`, in each line of the matrix.

It means that you need to replace all you allocation part by:

```
M = malloc(s * sizeof(int*));
k = 0;
while(k<s) {
    M[k] = malloc(s * sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<s;i++) {
        M[k][i] = 5;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Comment: This is no 2D array (aka matrix).

Comment: You have `s` pointers to type `int *`. Also, there isn't really anything wrong with using `realloc` to allocate. If `s` is not allocated, `realloc` behaves, by default, as `malloc`.

Comment: actually, if `s` is NULL, then realloc() acts like malloc()

Comment: this code still skips the error checking of the returned value from each call to malloc()

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = (int)sqrt(9);
int i,j,k;
int **M=NULL;

    k = 0;
    while(k<s){
        M = realloc(M, (k+1)*sizeof(int *));

        for(i=0;i<s;i++){
            M[k] = realloc(M[k], (i+1)*sizeof(int));
            M[k][i] = 5;
        }
        k++;
    }
```